# CSS3 Media Queries Width & Height

Tags: css, media-queries

I try to set this:

```
@media only screen and max-width320px{footer{text-align:left;}section,body{width:300px;}}
```

But not work what i do bad?

Comment: If you're using a CSS minifier and it's screwing up your media queries, find a new minifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width:320px){...}
```

You forgot some parentheses.

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width:305px){
body{width:300px;}
section{width:300px;}
.skills{padding:5px 630px 5px 0;}
} I try this still not work with html5 selectors what i do bad?